# How to get an html select-element with a querySelector in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-select, queryselector

I have a div with the classname "data" which contains 3 different elements: inpyt, select and textarea.

I would like to put the elements in an array with a querySelectorAll and loop over them to set the value back to empty.  The input en textarea elements work fine but I can't "catch" the select element.

In the querySelectorAll I first use the classname and then the tagnames.

What do I need to change to make it work properly?

```
<div class="data">
   <input></input>
   <select>
     <option value="" required></option>
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
     <option value="3">Three</option>
   </select>
   <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div>
   <button onclick="resetValues()"<Click</button>
</div>
```

```
function resetValues() {
   
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".data>input,textarea,select");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {arr[i].value = "";}
}
```

I tried to rewrite the querySelectorAll but it didn't work

```
document.querySelectorAll(".data>input,textarea,option[selected]");
document.querySelectorAll(".data>input,textarea,option[select]");
document.querySelectorAll(".data>input,textarea,select option");
document.querySelectorAll(".data>input,textarea,select>option");
document.querySelectorAll(".data>input,textarea,option");
```

Comment: _"What do I need to change to make it work properly?"_ - what in your code do we need to change, to make it _not_ work properly? It appears to work perfectly fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/d0qeg1bp/ (only things I changed, removed the `</input>` which does not belong there, and changed `<` to `>` so that the button text shows up properly. But it basically "worked" before that already ...)

Comment: Paste your HTML here: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the selector. The `,` separates distinct selectors. `.data>input,textarea,select` means

- `.data>input` OR
- `textarea` OR
- `select`

You should be using `.data>input,.data>textarea,.data>select`.

Or if your are using browsers that support the new [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) selector: `.data > :is(input,textarea,select)`